# jQuery Hide WooCommerce Cart

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to hide the WooCommerce Side Cart in wordpress when the item count is zero.

I have seen a few ways on StackOverflow but they only work on page refresh, not ideal.

I've finally got a jQuery script working.  This checks the item-count on page load (document ready) and then again each time the item count changes.  When the item-count is zero a class is appended to the basket div element, "hide-the-count".

I realised I'd left in some text, before my opening script tag, by mistake.  When I remove the text, the script no longer monitors for item-count changes (it works on load).

Console shows no errors although I suspect I'm making a mistake in the below code?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".xoo-wsc-items-count").each(function(){
            if (jQuery(this).text().trim() === '0') {
                jQuery(".xoo-wsc-basket").addClass("hide-the-count");
            }

        });
    });

jQuery("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "#item-count", function () {
     $(".xoo-wsc-items-count").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().trim() === '0') {
            $(".xoo-wsc-basket").addClass("hide-the-count");
        }
        else {
            $(".xoo-wsc-basket").removeClass("hide-the-count");
            }
        });

  });
```

[Link to Website with problem basket here](https://bigskyriders.com/product/raid-medlantic/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the script before the body tag, so it was not possible for the script to attach to the body element!  Placed in footer all fine.